# Documentation: Someone approved my topic and then rewrote my examples

Tags: support, documentation, reputation, documentation-proposals

I requested a new topic for the documentation for the Ruby language:

[Struct](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/5016/struct#t=201608042120303909348)

I also wrote three examples showing how to create them, access them and how to add methods to them.

The topic was approved, but then my examples were not approved and #matheus-moreira then submitted three examples showing how to create them, access them and how to add methods to them.  The same basic examples, with different strings and variable names.

My draft is still sitting in my drafts, ignored.

Why did my examples not get submitted, and what is the point of contributing to the docs if someone else can just take the efforts of our work away?

Comment: Looks like you didn't submit your draft.  Someone else came in and fulfilled your proposal, they didn't see your draft at all.

Comment: You mean this draft? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/drafts/60132 It does not look like you submitted it for review. Could you link to its rejection?

Comment: I ca't submit it for review until the topic is created, correct?  And the first notice I saw of the topic being created it already had the three examples.

Comment: Somewhat related [Chat Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32129388#32129388) There was a proposal that was clearly up for vote. I hit Accept, Rick hit Reject. I wanted to retain the work and find a home for it. Well, the chat link above depicts it. It all hung under me when I marched thru the Improve process. And I didn't write any of it and it looks like mine. Back on topic to you, David. Ah, why the guy tried to pawn it off as his with string changes, what ?!

Comment: No, you can both propose a topic and submit its first edit for review. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/76960

Comment: Then I'm missing something.  Nowhere in my drafts do I see the ability to submit the draft, I presumed that it would go along with the topic.

Comment: There is no "publish" button, apart from any publish I would have clicked when I first saved it.  Where am I supposed to see this?

Comment: Yeah, I think there's some bugginess to it. I have a draft of my own that I can neither discard nor submit. Not sure if there's already a bug report / support request for that issue. By the way if you don't @ someone and there is more than one commenter, no one gets pinged when you reply.

Comment: @frank, thanks.  :)

So - hopefully someone from support will see this and help me understand where my examples went.

I have submitted a bit of the info I had in my examples that wasn't in the new ones, hopefully those will go through.  Either way I have somewhat lost my energy for documentation.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you [proposed this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/72056) back on the 1st... But then retracted it a few minutes later.

Because it was retracted, no one could approve it. So it sat there in limbo, waiting for you to get back to it.

Two days later, [someone found your topic request and wrote a topic for it](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/73969). It's possible they used your draft for inspiration, but clearly they went in a little bit of a different direction. They couldn't have approved your draft, since it was still retracted at that point.

Comment: How exactly does one retract a proposed change?  I don't even know how to do that if I wanted to.

Comment: any time you click on the edit pencil for a doc entry (for any part of a topic) it retracts the whole thing, titles examples and all. Even if you don't make any changes, you need to then re-submit.

Comment: As mpag notes, editing retracts, @david. Perhaps we need a reminder to re-submit when this happens...

Comment: @shog9 or just allow users to work on the next draft of something while still having the orig in the queue for review.  Then if they re-submit have THAT replace the orig in the queue (and clear any already-reviewed flags or notify the reviewers).

Comment: @Shog9, Okay - but why does it not tell me this?  But more importantly - how do I resubmit?  I see no option to submit the draft anyways.

Comment: @mpag or separate both actions?

Comment: Not sure it'll let you submit now that a different topic has been created, @David. Even if it did, you'd probably want to just edit that instead. FWIW, it does tell you that editing will retract the draft, but I agree it could be a bit more insistent that you confirm before inadvertently abandoning it in limbo.

Comment: @Shog9:  1) It's not a different topic, my topic request was accepted.  2)  If editing retracts a draft, it should tell us, and 3) There should be a way to submit the draft.  Mine is stuck in limbo.

Comment: Can I get a screenshot of what you see when visiting [this draft](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/drafts/60132), @David?

Comment: @Shog9:  Now it gets weirder.  When I go to *my* drafts, I see the drafts that he submitted.  Is it possible that he took my drafts, edited them, and then submitted that so it would be "his" content?

http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/5016/struct?draftId=64396

Comment: (And it says "Submitted by..." with his info...  in *my* drafts)

Comment: *That* draft was created just a few hours before you posted this question, *after* the topic was already in existence, @David. It adds two new examples, neither of which currently appear on the topic (which makes sense, since it's still a draft - no one has proposed it much less seen it go into effect). Can I get a screenshot of what you're seeing with someone else's name on it?

Comment: Ah, wrong draft.  Here it is:  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/drafts/60132
Image:
http://imgur.com/a/BTddS

Looking at it I can see they created the topic because of the draft, but then ignored the draft.  They renamed it "Struct" from "Structs" which is weird, considering that the other datatypes are pluralized as topic names.